# How do you derive properties of the inverse of the function that satisfies a functional equation?

Tags: functional-analysis

It looks like there should be a way to do it: $e^{x}$ satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$.

Meanwhile its inverse, the natural logarithm, satisfies a similar looking but inverted equation: $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Surely there must be some way to manipulate or derive the second functional equation from the first functional equation, right?

Comment: I dont know if I understood right, but suppose that $f$ is bijective and satisfies the first equality and let $g$ be its inverse. Hence, $f(g(x)+g(y))=xy$. Then $g(f(g(x)+g(y)))=g(xy)$ and $g(x)+g(y)=g(xy)$.

Comment: You can label anything you want as an inverse, I'm certainly not stopping you.

Comment: Is there a generalized shortcut for doing this? It seems like you can almost swap each instance of a variable for the inverse function and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can't, but if you know that $f$ is invertible, then given $a,b$ you can take $x=f^{-1}(a)$, $y=f^{-1}(b)$, and then the first equality gives you 
$$
f^{-1}(ab)=f^{-1}(f(x)f(y))=f^{-1}(f(x+y))=x+y=f^{-1}(a)+f^{-1}(b). 
$$
As you can do this for any $a,b$, you have obtained the second equality.